# Why this sequence $1 \rightarrow \mathbb{U}_1/\mathbb{U}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{U}/\mathbb{U}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p^* \rightarrow 1$ is exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, exact-sequence

I'm trying to understand the algebraic properties of p-adic numbers in the "algebraic" part of Serre' book "A Course in arithmetic". In the chapter 2 section 3.

$\mathbb{U} := \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ the units of the p-adic integers, $\mathbb{U}_n := 1 +p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$ and
$\mathbb{F}_p^* = \mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z}^*$.

He says that this sequence $1 \rightarrow \mathbb{U}_1/\mathbb{U}_n  \rightarrow   \mathbb{U}/\mathbb{U}_n \rightarrow  \mathbb{F}_p^* \rightarrow 1$ is exact, but

he doesn't say what are the maps. What are the maps involved?

And, why these maps implies the exactness of the sequence?

Comment: The first map is the inclusion $\mathbb{U}_1 \subset \mathbb{U}$. The second map is the reduction mod $p$. The exactness follows because you’re quotienting $1 \rightarrow \mathbb{U}_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p^{\times} \rightarrow 1$ by a subgroup of the kernel of the surjection.

Comment: @Mindlack  the statement that you said, is true in general? Because i can see that the $Im(i)$ is contained in the Ker($\pi$) but i can't see the other inclusion. ($i$ is the inclusion and $\pi$ is the reduction mod$p$) (and when you say "surjection" do you mean $\pi$?)

Comment: Yes, “the surjection” means $\pi$ here. And yes, my statement is general for any short exact sequence of abelian groups. Here, $ker(\pi)$ is the set of elements of $\mathbb{U}$ congruent to $1$ mod $p$, so they are the $1+pz$, $z \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, si the elements of the image of $i$.

Answer (score 2):

The first map is the inclusion $i: \mathbb{U}_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{U}$ and the second map is the reduction mod $p$ $\pi: \mathbb{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$.

The exactness follows because you’re quotienting the exact sequence $1 \rightarrow \mathbb{U}_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ by a subgroup of the kernel of the surjection.